# Css link to php file

Tags: php, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj6Mx.png)I added a css link to my php file, but it won't show the changes.
My css file is named register.css and my php file is named register.php.

```
<?php
    include("includes/config.php");
    include("includes/classes/Account.php");
    include("includes/classes/Constants.php");

    $account = new Account($con);

    include("includes/handlers/register-handler.php");
    include("includes/handlers/login-handler.php");

    function getInputValue($name) {
        if(isset($_POST[$name])) {
            echo $_POST[$name];
        }
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to Napster!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/register.css"/>
</head>'
```

My css file is in assets file which is in same file as my php file.
I am using xamp and sublime text.

Comment: must be browser cache. try pressing Ctrl+f5

Comment: are you sure that is the correct url? check it on the browser and inspect if the url send you to your css file

Comment: tried that didnt worked@Rumesh

Comment: @AlejandroMaliachiQuintana it shows  when i inspect the page but the file is  shown empty

Comment: change the name of your css file and try again

Comment: does 404 error comes?

Comment: @Rumesh yes it shows 404 error

Comment: then definitely it should be browser cache. are you using chrome

Comment: @Rumesh i tried it in both chrome and firefox emtyed the cache and reloaded it sti nothing is happening

Comment: would you mind showing your file structure?

Comment: would you mind to post the picture when the inspection send you to your css file @user9581667?

Comment: @suzan it is under xamp-htdocs-napster-assets-css-register.css                                                                                                 .                                                               -incudes                                                        .                                                               -index.php&register.php

Comment: you can post the image of the file structure of your files

Comment: how can i add image in coments

Comment: @user9581667 you can't in comments but you can in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the issue is either browser cache or related to path..

please try

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/register.css?v=1.1"/>
```

if register.php is not in root folder then try..

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/register.css?v=1.1"/>
```

here ?v=1.1 is added to load updated css. whenever you make changes in css file, simply chage v=1.1 with another number like v=1.2 etc... to avoid clear cache in browser and load updated css...